# HTML5 - Animated Cursor

Tags: html, cursor, custom-cursor

My HTML document needs a custom cursor linked to an animated gif file. 
What is wrong with my cursor properties?

```
<!doctype html> <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                cursor: url('images/hero.gif'), auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice Q , just use one set interval an make animated cursor ! i will try it now

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor; I believe the relevant aspect is "Animatable: no".

Comment: <!doctype html> <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                body{
                    cursor:  url('images/hero.png'), auto;
                    cursor:  url('images/hero.png'), pointer;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
       
        </body>
    </html>

Comment: or this .. ?

        <!doctype html> <html>
           <head>
               <style type="text/css">
            body {
                cursor: url('hero.ico'), default;
            }        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       
    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

An animated PNG or GIF will **not** create an animated cursor. This is a rendering engine limitation.

Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property